# Не запускается Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu

Уважаемые Линуксоиды!

Я тут на днях создал себе проблему, после чего моя система перестала загружаться.  :D Все началось с установки новой версии Kivy (кроссплатформенный фреймворк для разработки приложений для Android/Linux/Windows/iOS). Стояла версия 1.9.0, решил обновить до 1.9.1. Обновил репозитории, зашел в Synaptic, чекнул новую версию, установил. Поскольку для работы Kivy необходимы такие библиотеки как gstreamer, python-opengl, pyenchat, Cython, sdl2 и другие, и поскольку для каждой версии Kivy нужна своя версия библиотеки, у меня свежеустановленная версия Kivy 1.9.1, конечно же, не заработала. Побродив по форумам, узнал, какие версии библиотек нужны для корректной работы Kivy версии 1.9.1. Проверил версии библиотек, которые установлены у меня и которые юзает Kivy. Все отлично, все самое свежее, за исключением gstreamer - у меня была версия 0.10, а для работы Kivy 1.9.1 требовалась веряия 1.0. Зашел в Synaptic, чекнул версию gstreamer 1.0, установил, запустил свой проект на Kivy - не работает. Вываливается лог, о версиях OpenGL, sdl и пр. чепуха. Ну, думаю, ладно, очевидно, конфликт версий gstreamer, поскольку у меня установлены теперь и версия 0.10 и 1.0. Размяв пальцы, перекрестившись, снес начисто версию gstreamer 0.10. Да, Synaptic честно предупредил, что, мол, удаление этого пакета и сопутствующих ему, зартагивает другие пакеты, такие, как Pulseaudio, Opera, некоторые другие и пакет, с именем linux-mint-далее-не-помню. Да и черт с ним, подумал я, сутки просидевший за компом, пытаясь завести Kivy 1.9.1, и со всей силы тыкнул по клавише Enter! Synaptic благополучно удалил все дерево библиотек gstreamer 0.10. В итоге Kivy 1.9.1 так и не запустился, зато из меню пропали приложения Gimp, Opera, Wine, Software Manager, WxGlade, Krusader и, наверное, другие, о которых я пока не знаю, а при запуске терминала вместо коровьих цитат стала появляться строка - "/usr/bin/mint-fortune: No cearch file of dyrectiry". Пережагружаю систему и через пару секунд удивленно таращусь на заставку Ubuntu 14.04. Нет, не мерещится - действительно, грузится Ubuntu 14.04 вместо привычного логотипа Linux Mint. Все. Загрузка останавливается на действии "Stopping Samba Autoreload Integration".

Захожу в иксы из-под рута - все нормально. Проект на Kivy 1.9.1 отлично запускается и работает. Приплыли, думаю. Запустил Synaptic (под рутом), установил все пакеты, связанные с linux-mint-..., которые были похожи на тот который я снес вместе с gstreamer. Строка в терминале- "/usr/bin/mint-fortune: No cearch file of dyrectiry" исчезла, появилось в меню приложение Software Manager и др., появилась родная заставка Linux Mint при загрузке системы. Удалил файлы .ICEauthority, .profile. Но система так и не грузится от пользователя - "Stopping Samba Autoreload Integration".

Подскажите, что я такого натворил и ксть ли способ вернуть все?!

Comment: В Synaptic есть история. "Файл" -> "История". Посмотри что ты там удалил, что поставил.

Comment: А вообще для таких эксперементов лучше делать сначала в виртуалке. Если всё ок - переносить в реальную ОС.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не знал об истории! Открыл - и волосы встали дыбом от того, что я удалил!

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа. Если помогло - ответь как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Synaptic есть история. "Файл" -> "История". Посмотри что ты там удалил, что поставил.